# Получить значения координат по осям с FigureCanvasTkAgg

Tags: python, tkinter, matplotlib

Я хочу в программе получать массив значений х и у, после того как масштабировал график на FigureCanvasTkAgg с помощью кнопок NavigationToolbar2Tk во время работы программы. Имею в виду те значения, которые находятся на отмасштабированном графике, а не на всем графике.
Смотрел реализацию либ, там черт ногу сломит. FigureCanvasTkAgg унаследован от 2 классов, каждый из которых еще унаследован от 1 класса. При этом большая часть действий с ними происходит по происхождению событий tk Events. Есть кто шарит?
[image: Пример]

Comment: Нашел способ получить список из xticks и yticks. Нужно обращаться к API самого axes. Оказывается при масштабировании графика на canvas меняется и привязанный к нему figure, следовательно и привязанный к figure axes. Но все равно очень запутанная связь между axes, figure, canvas, toolbar.